# Mobile website opens profile page in desktop mode

Tags: bug

When I open Stack Overflow in mobile Chrome on Android 8 and tap on the reputation changes button (and only this button), often my profile page in desktop mode opens unexpectedly.

[image]

[image]

#### Updates, reacting to comments with more information

Like I said, it happens *often*, not *always*, i.e. the error is sporadic. When the site works normally and I tap the achievements button, I see the expected drop-down list of achievements (sorry, when uploading images on a desktop PC, where I am editing my question, the screenshots are displayed in a huge size and the markdown here does not have a canonical way to determine the displayed size):

[image]

> *Ivar:* The achievements button in the top bar is an anchor that links to the page you ended up at. Normally JavaScript kicks in to open the usual modal when you click it, but if you click too soon or if the script is broken, it will redirect you instead. –

All I can say is that the page seemed to be fully loaded already in all cases I tried this. At least Chrome's loading bar was not visible anymore in those instances. It also sometimes happens after clicking or swiping "back" and retrying. I cannot say if the page was loaded in an incomplete fashion, but at least it gave no indication of it. It might explain the sporadic occurrence of this phenomenon, but it happens about every other day when I use Stack Overflow on my mobile device.

As for "click too soon", why would that lead me to my Stack Exchange profile instead of displaying my Stack Overflow achievements? Who would intentionally program a website like this? Even a non-dynamic default link could lead me to the Stack Overflow achievements overview page, if the JS for displaying the drop-down menu is not loaded. The SE profile simply makes no sense and is a **bug**.

---

> *Heretic Monkey:* Android 8 is four versions behind the current version. If the Chrome version is likewise not updated, it may be that you're in unsupported-land...

Thanks for the thought, but Chrome is up to date on that device, version 98. Please also remember, I described the bug as sporadic. If Chrome could not handle the JS correctly, it would never work.

---

> *Catija:* You're not really on the mobile version of the site in your first screenshot.

Technically, that might be true, if now you have one code base and a reactive website. I am not a web developer, and for my user experience it does not matter. What I can say is that by default, on my mobile device the website looks like on my first screenshot above, which changes when activating Chrome's "desktop mode" option:

[image]

[image]

This is what I mean by the term "mobile website".

> The page you're being taken to is your profile on stackexchange.com - in fact, it's your reputation page on that site... this is our backup target for the achievements trophy in cases where the JavaScript doesn't work.

Like I said before, the back-up site if JS does not work should be the Stack Overflow achievements page. Sorry, if I am not expressing myself clearly in the terms the experts here might use. What I mean, is this view:

[image]

Comment: The second image is of Stack Exchange, not Stack Overflow, and is of your global profile. If you open your SO Profile, it's Mobile View. I *assume* that the main SE site (not Meta Stack Exchange) doesn't have a responsive version yet.

Comment: The achievements button in the top bar is an anchor that links to the page you ended up at. Normally JavaScript kicks in to open the usual modal when you click it, but if you click too soon or if the script is broken, it will redirect you instead.

Comment: The comments are not helpful. I am clearly starting from Stack Overflow and clicking my achievements button. There is no sensible explanation for it opening the site on the second screenshot, especially not in desktop mode. If I reload the first page and click on the same button again, the normal drop-down listing my latest achievements opens. A bug is a bug is a bug.

Comment: Android 8 is four versions behind the current version. If the Chrome version is likewise not updated, it may be that you're in unsupported-land...

Comment: @kriegaex The comments you deride as not helpful *are, in fact, helpful*. They explain what's happening in more technical detail. This helps other people looking into this to not spend as much time investigating. Those comments aren't saying it's not a problem. That they don't resolve your issue is expected. Only you and SE might be able to do things that resolve your issue. The best anyone other than SE staff can do in response to such a bug report is to attempt to explain it, and, maybe, provide a work around. Responding negatively to people trying to help is usually counterproductive.

Comment: @Makyen, I have not _derided_ any comments, I have _judged_ them as not helpful, because they were not helping me to explain or solve my problem. Actually, I started on the "contact" page, because I wanted to contact SE staff directly. When trying to send a message there, there was not category about technical problems with the website but instead a link to the community here at Meta. I was under the false impression that SE staff is reading this and helping to resolve issues. Sorry for hoping for too much, but thanks for explaining.

Comment: To everyone who commented so far: I have replied in my updated answer, because I uploaded more screenshots explaining my words. P.S.: Sorry for the huge, non-resizable (unless using HTML IMG tags) screenshots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few things going on here that I think are leading to some confusion but, as far as I can tell, I don't think there's a bug here. Please feel free to update your question with more information if you have something additional to add.

1. **You're not *really* on the mobile version of the site in your first screenshot.** - Yes, you're on a mobile device but we don't have a mobile version of the site any more.
   The mobile version of the site was very different looking and has been deprecated as of... two weeks ago, or so. Now, there are some outstanding bits and pieces we need to clean up, including removing the "Mobile" button in the footer but, essentially, you're on the full site.
2. **The page you're being taken to is your profile on `stackexchange.com`** - in fact, it's your reputation page on that site... this is our backup target for the achievements trophy in cases where the JavaScript doesn't work. It also is where the achievements button will take you if you click it before the JavaScript loads. It happens to me from time to time and it's just a reminder to slow down a bit.
   The achievements button links to your network-wide reputation page because the achievements button *shows* your network-wide achievements, not the ones for Stack Overflow only.
3. **The `stackexchange.com` site doesn't have a mobile version.** It's a legacy page that hasn't gotten much (any) love in recent years and so we don't have a mobile-friendly view for it.

It's worth noting that (as far as I'm aware) the other items in the top bar have similar actions... e.g. the inbox will go to your network-wide inbox.

If this doesn't address your concerns, please, let us know. I'm not sure I'm understanding the issue otherwise, so editing your question to add more details may help.

Comment: I have replied in my updated answer, because I also uploaded more screenshots explaining my words.

Comment: My answer explicitly states why we link to the network achievements - "*The achievements button links to your network-wide reputation page because the achievements button shows your network-wide achievements, not the ones for Stack Overflow only.*" You are welcome to disagree with the behavior but that doesn't mean it's a bug.

Comment: Users and product providers often disagree about what constitutes a bug and what not. I am seeing that a lot in my work as an agile coach. Providers tend to say: "This behaviour is intended, hence not a bug." While users say: "This is counter-intuitive and does not fit user expectations. Instead, the behaviour should be such and such. For us it is therefore a bug." So OK, conceding that it might not be a bug by your definition, in my updated question I showed a screenshot of the page I expect the link to go to as a backup for missing JS.

Comment: I.e., I criticised in a constructive way, suggesting how you could both have your fallback and still meet user expectations, while staying on the Stack Overflow domain and displaying a mobile website at the same time. Win-win! I mean [this view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhCP1.jpg) of URL https://stackoverflow.com/users/1082681/kriegaex?tab=reputation. Wouldn't that be much better than https://stackexchange.com/users/1087271/kriegaex?tab=inbox? Then it does not matter that Stack Exchange is not mobile-capable.

Comment: @kriegaex No, it wouldn't. The achievements menu displays achievements *across the entire network*. It is possible for it to be lit up with only changes on other sites, in which case linking to the current site's reputation page would give the user no information whatsoever. It goes correctly to the network profile because it is a network-wide representation of your account loaded into a drop-down.

Comment: Actually, as a user I care more about staying on the community I am currently surfing on and seeing my chievement updates there than anywhere else, so the link I suggested is clearly the better alternative for me, because it matches user expectations. As soon as the page loads correctly again and JS is available, in the drop-down menu I can see my achievements on other sites, which is fine. But like most users, I am 95% active in a single community I care about, in my case SO. If your choice of fallback URL is so great, why does it irritate me so much? Maybe I am not smart enough?

Comment: @kriegaex It would be inappropriate to cast your personal preferences on what the button should do upon everyone on the network merely because it would be more convenient to you. It is linked there specifically because the network page matches the behavior of the drop-down. The user expectation is that, in the absence of modals loading onto the page, they find all the information that would have been displayed there. Your expectation just seems to be different, and there's not a lot we can do about that. You certainly shouldn't let it irritate you and it has no bearing on intelligence.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have accepted this answer, even though I am not happy with the outcome. But the purpose is to understand why what I am experiencing on my mobile device happens and what the product provider's intent behind that behaviour is. These goals have been achieved.

Comment: "It also is where the achievements button will take you if you click it before the JavaScript loads ... it's just a reminder to slow down a bit." - This is bad UX. It's a bug, not a feature reminding us to slow down.

Comment: @Joundill I may have been a bit glib but it's definitely a feature, not a bug. If the button has nothing to connect to for people who don't have JS (e.g. people who may be on slow connections or have older machines), having a button that does nothing for some users is the bad UX.

Comment: @Catija That's definitely not how I've experienced it as a user. If the button requires javascript to be loaded it should either be hidden until the javascript is loaded, or the page it links to should be the same as the dropdown. Every time I've hit this issue, I've thought it was a bug.